# How I can download those lib 64 bit?

Tags: android, build, 64-bit, lib

Please i had app works on 32 bit , and now I would like to build it to works on 64 bit.

I have add those on ndk, but I don't know how I can get the lib missing for 64 bit.

Thanks

** ndk {
abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v8a", "x86", "mips" , "arm64-v8a","x86_64"
}
}**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V5he.png)

** ndk {
abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v8a", "x86", "mips" , "arm64-v8a","x86_64"
}
}**

[

Comment: You need not only the libraries but also the correct version. If you have a project as source code make sure to only use libraries that has the libraries in an arm 8a version included.